# Why isn't the submit button working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have written this code testing out the $scope feature as I have just started learning AngularJS. However, whenever I click the submit button, nothing happens.

This is my JS file below.

```
var app = angular.module('permissions', []);

app.controller('testAppCtrl', ['$scope', function testAppCtrl($scope) {
  'use strict';

  $scope.details = {
    itemId: "",
    userID: ""
  };

  $scope.register = function () {
    console.log('User clicked change', details.itemId);
  };

  $scope.fullDetails = function () {
    return details.itemId + " " + details.userId;
  };
}]);
```

This is my PHP file below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/angular-permission-test.js"></script>

<div id="myForm">
  <form name="myForm" action="" ng-app="permissions" ng-submit="register()">
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <body ng-controller="testAppCtrl">

        ItemId: <input type="text" ng-model="details.itemId"> {{details.itemId}}<br><br>
        UserId: <input type="text" ng-model="details.userId"> {{details.userId}}<br><br>
        <input name="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Change" ng-click="register()">

        {{ fullDetails() }}
      </body>
  </form>
</div>
```

I can't seem to find the problem in the code. I have tried many solutions but none have had any apparent effect on it.

Also, any improvements to the code will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you boostrapping like that?

Comment: You have an invalid markup.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean by bootstrapping like that. Could you care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I think is with the structure of your HTML. Because angular scope is resolved from the HTML elements parent child hierarchy.

Your `testAppCtrl` is in body (which is inside your form), the `register()` function is inside the scope of `testAppCtrl` (but you are trying to access it outside the body). So, you cannot access it from outside in hierarchy. Keep the `Body` outside and `form` inside. Also the ng-app should be at the same or higher level of your ng-controller. Because you can bind your controllers to the app/module and not the reverse.

So, the code should be something like this,

```
<body  ng-app="permissions" ng-controller="testAppCtrl">    
    <div id="myForm">
      <form name="myForm" action="" ng-submit="register()">
          <h1>Test</h1>
            ItemId: <input type="text" ng-model="details.itemId"> {{details.itemId}}<br><br>
            UserId: <input type="text" ng-model="details.userId"> {{details.userId}}<br><br>
            <input name="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Change" ng-click="register()">

            {{ fullDetails() }}

      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I noticed. ng-app should be declared inside ng-controller.
you are returning plain variables instead of the scope variables.

Anyway, here's the fix.

```js
var app = angular.module('permissions', []);

app.controller('testAppCtrl', ['$scope',
  function testAppCtrl($scope) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.details = {
      itemId: "",
      userID: ""
    };

    $scope.register = function() {
      console.log('User clicked change', $scope.details.itemId);
    };

    $scope.fullDetails = function() {
      return $scope.details.itemId + " " + $scope.details.userId;
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="permissions">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.13" data-semver="1.3.13" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testAppCtrl">
  <div id="myForm">
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="register()">
      <h1>Test</h1> ItemId:
      <input type="text" ng-model="details.itemId" />{{details.itemId}}
      <br />
      <br />UserId:
      <input type="text" ng-model="details.userId" />{{details.userId}}
      <br />
      <br />
      <input name="submitBtn" type="submit" />{{ fullDetails() }}

    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it works? Check the snippet. It directly writes in when you type something in textboxes.